# How to replace multiple Line Breaks with single Line break from nvarchar string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a column 'CN_Text' of `nvarchar` type which will store notes with multiple line breaks.

Example -

```
Aaaaaaaa....



Bbbbb



Cccccccc
```

I want to replace multiple consecutive line breaks with single line break. Like

```
Aaaaaaaa....

Bbbbb

Ccccccccc
```

How I can replace this multiple line breaks with single line break?

Comment: Does it need to work for `CRLF`, `CR`, or some combination?

Answer (score 5):

First replace all the new line to a different set of characters then replace those characters with new line as below.

```
select string = replace(replace(replace('Aaaaaaaa....


Bbbbb


Cccccccc','
','<>'),'><',''),'<>','
')
```

Comment: Cool trick. If all of his strings are `CRLF`, you could further simplify by simply replacing `LFCR` with an empty string.

Comment: This is going to be clean up script, which is going to alter all rows of large database. End of the script, expectation is there should not be a single string which has two consecutive line breaks. If in string anywhere there is more than one line breaks that need to be reduced to only single line break. Note : string has more than 10000 lines(including multiple consecutive empty lines)

Comment: it was just an example, you can replace your new line with $##$ also, then replace #$$# with empty then finally replace $##$ with new line.

Comment: Not working perfectly. It is removing all line breaks. I need one line break.if multiple consecutive lines are there.  Input Text : 'Asit
  
  
  Singh
  KKKKKKKK



  '   OutPut Text : 'Asit
  
  
  Singh
  KKKKKKKK
  '

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking this:

```
DECLARE @A nvarchar(500) 
SET @A = 'Aaaaaaaa....


         Bbbbb


         Cccccccc';

SET @A = 
  replace(replace(replace(
    replace(
      replace(@A,
      CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),' '),
      ' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '),
      ' ',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10));


PRINT @A
```

First remove all the break lines in your text, later change the consecutive spaces with just one, and finally change the space by the break line you need.

Comment: In this case, if in single line we have text with multi spaces it will replace with new line. e.g. ' AAAAA...     BBBBB   ccccccc'

Comment: I want to set focus back to the place where it was before removing extra lines. How  i can restore Cursor.